# laravel two table join using model and controller and showing all data

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables `courses` and `mtests`  like  as 
[image]

in the course table two fields  `id` and `name`

[image: mtests table]

in matests table have four fields like `id` and `course_id`  this `course_id` and `id` in course 
table foreign key used

i have two model like `mtest` and `course`  how to perform join operation in `mtest` and `course` model and get result please help me.

// mtest model code

```
  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class mtest extends Model
  {
 public function mycourse()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(course::class);
  }

}
```

//  course model code

```
 namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class course extends Model
{


 }
```

mtest controller code

```
   public function index()
    {
    //$mtest = mtest::latest()->paginate(5);
    $mtest = mtest::has('mycourse')->get();

    print_r($mtest);

    // return view('dashboard.mtest.index',compact('mtest'))
    //  ->with('i',(request()->input('page',1)-1)*5); 
 }
```

how to get all field in both tables in our controller please help me.

Comment: You need to define relationship in course model too. I guess it's a belongsTo relation.

Answer (score 0):

use laravel `with()` to get the relation data from another table

```
$mtest = ModelName::with('mycourse')->get();
print_r($mtest);
```